C++ implementation of a keyed priority queue / binary heap
I wrote an implementation of a keyed priority queue in C++ and wanted to get some feedback on it.
I tried to model it after the std::unordered_map and std::priority_queue in terms of template parameters.
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

/**
 * @brief Priority queue that associates each priority with a hashable key.
 * Priorities are added with a user-defined key, and priorities can be modified
 * or removed using the key. Maximum priorities are placed at the top by
 * default.
 * @details pop, push, getPriority, removeKey have O(log(n)) time complexity,
 * assuming comparison takes O(1) time complexity.
 * @param K Key type.
 * @param V Value type.
 * @param Compare Comparison object that can compare values for priority
 * ordering. The default is std::less<V>.
 * @param Hash The hash for key types.
 * @param KeyEqual Object for determining equality between keys.
 */
template <class K, class V, class Compare = std::less<V>,
          class Hash = std::hash<K>, class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<K>>
class KeyedPriorityQueue {
  public:
    /**
     * @brief Default constructor creates a maximum priority queue.
     */
    KeyedPriorityQueue() : cmp_(Compare{}) {}

    /**
     * @brief Constructor that uses a custom comparison function.
     * @param cmp A function object for custom comparison that must be in the
     * form of (const V &a, const V &b) -> bool, where the return value
     * represents a < b.
     * @example Using a cmp of (const V& a, const V& b) { return a > b; } would
     * specify a minimum priority queue.
     */
    KeyedPriorityQueue(const std::function<bool(const V &, const V &)> &cmp)
        : cmp_(cmp) {}

    /**
     * @brief Returns boolean indicating if priority queue is empty.
     */
    bool isEmpty() const { return priorities_.empty(); }

    /**
     * @brief Return size of priority queue.
     */
    std::size_t size() const { return priorities_.size(); }

    /**
     * @brief Delete all entries currently in the priority queue.
     */
    void clear() {
        priorities_.clear();
        keyIdx_.clear();
    }

    /**
     * @brief Return reference to top of priority queue, returning a (key,
     * value) pair. Throws if empty.
     */
    const std::pair<K, V> &top() const {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw std::out_of_range("queue is empty");
        }

        return priorities_[0];
    }

    /**
     * @brief Insert priority if key does not exist; otherwise, the existing
     * priority associated with the key is updated.
     * @param key Key to insert.
     * @param priority Priority to insert.
     */
    void push(const K &key, const V &priority) {
        if (!containsKey(key)) {
            priorities_.emplace_back(key, priority);

            std::size_t idx = size() - 1;
            keyIdx_[key] = idx;
            moveUpwards(idx);

            return;
        }

        std::size_t idx = keyIdx_[key];
        V oldPriority = std::move(priorities_[idx].second);
        priorities_[idx].second = priority;

        if (cmp_(oldPriority, priority)) {
            moveUpwards(idx);
        } else {
            moveDownwards(idx);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief R-value priority version of push().
     * @param key Key to insert.
     * @param priority Priority to insert.
     */
    void push(const K &key, V &&priority) {
        if (!containsKey(key)) {
            priorities_.emplace_back(key, std::move(priority));

            std::size_t idx = size() - 1;
            keyIdx_[key] = idx;
            moveUpwards(idx);

            return;
        }

        std::size_t idx = keyIdx_[key];
        V oldPriority = std::move(priorities_[idx].second);
        priorities_[idx].second = std::move(priority);

        if (cmp_(oldPriority, priorities_[idx].second)) {
            moveUpwards(idx);
        } else {
            moveDownwards(idx);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief Remove the top of the priority queue, if it exists; do nothing
     * otherwise.
     */
    void pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        if (size() == 1) {
            clear();
            return;
        }

        keyIdx_.erase(priorities_[0].first);

        priorities_[0].first = std::move(priorities_[size() - 1].first);
        priorities_[0].second = std::move(priorities_[size() - 1].second);
        priorities_.pop_back();

        keyIdx_[priorities_[0].first] = 0;

        moveDownwards(0);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Returns boolean indicating if a key exists in the priority queue.
     * @param key Key to check.
     */
    bool containsKey(const K &key) const { return keyIdx_.count(key); }

    /**
     * @brief Return reference to the priority associated with the key. Throws
     * if key does not exist.
     * @param key Key used to obtain associated priority.
     */
    const V &getPriority(const K &key) const {
        if (!containsKey(key)) {
            throw std::out_of_range("key does not exist");
        }

        return priorities_[keyIdx_.at(key)].second;
    }

    /**
     * @brief Remove the priority associated with the key, if the key exists.
     * Does nothing otherwise.
     * @param key Key used to remove associated priority.
     */
    void removeKey(const K &key) {
        if (!containsKey(key)) {
            return;
        }

        std::size_t idx = keyIdx_[key];
        if (idx == size() - 1) {
            keyIdx_.erase(key);
            priorities_.pop_back();
            return;
        }

        V oldPriority = std::move(priorities_[idx].second);

        priorities_[idx].first = std::move(priorities_[size() - 1].first);
        priorities_[idx].second = std::move(priorities_[size() - 1].second);
        priorities_.pop_back();

        keyIdx_[priorities_[idx].first] = idx;
        keyIdx_.erase(key);

        if (cmp_(oldPriority, priorities_[idx].second)) {
            moveUpwards(idx);
        } else {
            moveDownwards(idx);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief Const iterators that expose the internal keys and priorities.
     */
    typename std::vector<std::pair<K, V>>::const_iterator begin() const {
        return priorities_.begin();
    }
    typename std::vector<std::pair<K, V>>::const_iterator end() const {
        return priorities_.end();
    }

  private:
    /**
     * @brief Comparison function used to determine priority.
     */
    const std::function<bool(const V &, const V &)> cmp_;

    /**
     * @brief Vector containing elements of the priority queue.
     */
    std::vector<std::pair<K, V>> priorities_;

    /**
     * @brief Mapping of {key : idx}, where idx represents the index location of
     * the entry in the priorities_ vector;
     */
    std::unordered_map<K, std::size_t, Hash, KeyEqual> keyIdx_;

    /**
     * @brief If necessary, move the entry at idx upwards after a priority
     * increase.
     */
    void moveUpwards(std::size_t idx) {
        int parentIdx = (idx - 1) / 2;
        while (idx >= 1 &&
               cmp_(priorities_[parentIdx].second, priorities_[idx].second)) {
            keyIdx_[priorities_[parentIdx].first] = idx;
            keyIdx_[priorities_[idx].first] = parentIdx;

            std::swap(priorities_[idx], priorities_[parentIdx]);

            idx = parentIdx;
            parentIdx = (idx - 1) / 2;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief If necessary, move the entry at idx downwards after a priority
     * decrease.
     */
    void moveDownwards(std::size_t idx) {
        std::size_t maxPriorityIdx = getChildrenMax(idx);
        while (maxPriorityIdx != idx) {
            keyIdx_[priorities_[idx].first] = maxPriorityIdx;
            keyIdx_[priorities_[maxPriorityIdx].first] = idx;

            std::swap(priorities_[idx], priorities_[maxPriorityIdx]);

            idx = maxPriorityIdx;
            maxPriorityIdx = getChildrenMax(idx);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @brief Helper function for moveDownwards.
     * @details Return the index of the entry with the largest priority, out of
     * the nodes {idx, idx.left, idx.right}, where the left and right nodes of
     * the heap may be logically null.
     */
    std::size_t getChildrenMax(std::size_t idx) const {
        std::size_t maxPriorityIdx = idx;

        std::size_t leftIdx = 2 * idx + 1;
        if (leftIdx < size() && cmp_(priorities_[maxPriorityIdx].second,
                                     priorities_[leftIdx].second)) {
            maxPriorityIdx = leftIdx;
        }

        std::size_t rightIdx = 2 * idx + 2;
        if (rightIdx < size() && cmp_(priorities_[maxPriorityIdx].second,
                                      priorities_[rightIdx].second)) {
            maxPriorityIdx = rightIdx;
        }

        return maxPriorityIdx;
    }
};



A quick note: if you're modelling after std::priority_queue, it doesn't have any of the member types (size_type, value_type, etc.) that those classes share.

I am not a professional C++ programmer, yet I can provide some minor stylistic advices.
Intro
Actually, you have implemented a binary heap that runs Insert, Update, ExtractMinimum in all \$\mathcal{O}(\log N)\$ time. Nice work!
Advice 1 - Rename class parameter names
You have two main type parameters: K and V. K as the data key and V as the "value". Actually, V is used as the priority type; thus, I suggest you rename V to Priority and K to Key.
Advice 2 - Use header guards
I would place the entire header file content into:
#ifndef COM_CODEREVIEW_STACKEXCHANGE_JZHU379_UTIL_BINARY_HEAP_H
#define COM_CODEREVIEW_STACKEXCHANGE_JZHU379_UTIL_BINARY_HEAP_H

// Your entire binary heap code.

#endif // COM_CODEREVIEW_STACKEXCHANGE_JZHU379_UTIL_BINARY_HEAP_H

Advice 3 - Wrap your heap implementation in a namespace
Along the Advice 2, I would also place your actual code into a namespace:
namespace com::stackexchange::codereview::jzhu379::util {
    // Code here.
} // end of namespace ::stackexchange::codereview::jzhu379::util

Advice 4 - Wrong default priority comparator
You have:
class Compare = std::less<Priority> // Note Priority against V.

Unfortunately, that yields a max heap. If you want the default priority order be such that the lower priority key, the higher the actual priority, you must do:
class Compare = std::greater<Priority>


Advice 5 - A minor neat pick
You have:
bool containsKey(const Key& key) const { return keyIdx_.count(key); }

I understand that you implicitly convert size_t to bool, but why not do instead:
bool containsKey(const Key& key) const { return keyIdx_.count(key) > 0; }
                                                                   ^^^^

Advice 6 - Additional advice
You use two functions: moveUpwards and moveDownwards. What comes to implementing binary heaps, the usual and customary names for those are siftUp and siftDown.
Advice 7 - pop returns silently
Your pop returns silently when the heap is empty. The std::priority_queue throws an exception.

Thanks for the feedback. The only correction I have for your suggestions is for #4. The default std::priority_queue is a max heap, and it uses a default Compare type of std::less<...> (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

@jzhu379 Oops, my bad.  I really didn’t know that. Just ignore the 4th advice.
